# std::vector or std::list for std::unordered_map buckets?

Tags: c++, list, vector, unordered-map

What would the preferred data structure for when two keys map to the same bucket in an `std::ordered_map<T>`. I am not sure whether it would be better to use a `std::vector<T>` (which would requiring copying all of the elements when reaching the capacity but quick iteration) or a `std::list<T>` which would be easy to add new elements but slower to iterate over?

### std::vector

- Quick for iterating over elements
- Bad if run out of capacity as need to copy all elements in to new memory

### std::list

- Quick for adding/deleting nodes
- Bad for iterating over as elements not in continuous memory

Comment: The answer depends on usage pattern.

Comment: You left out `std::deque`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without knowing your exact usage pattern and workload, I'd say that `std::vector` is better. This is true most of the time, and I'll try and explain why below.

1. Most of the time, you do a lot more lookups into a hash table than insertions. Lookups require iteration over a bucket, and insertions require adding elements and potentially resizing. Therefore, it makes more sense to optimize for the more common use case.
2. Every insert internally needs to do a lookup, so you will have at least as many lookups as insert; commonly much more.
3. Most of the time the average number of keys per bucket is low. This translates into working with a small vector vs. a small list. And resizing a small vector (which involves copying of elements) will be fast.
4. That vector "resizing" generally doesn't happen very often, so you don't have to be irrationally afraid of it. (Although you should note that when the vector is small, the resizing does happen more often. This is true for all implementations I know, but it's also trivial to rectify/circumvent.)
5. Iteration over a vector is *a lot* faster than iteration over a list. *A lot*.
6. Even resizing and copying (or moving) a vector can be as fast (or almost as fast) as adding an element into a list.
7. With proper "move" support in your data types, resizing a vector becomes even less of an overhead.
8. You can preallocate some number of elements with a vector, and almost completely eliminate all resizing in buckets. For example, if you know that 99% of your buckets will contain 3 keys or less, you can reserve 3 or 4 elements for each of the vectors and forget about resizing (almost.)
9. Vectors (specially when their element type is small) are much more space-efficient than linked lists. A `std::list` needs to keep two additional pointers per element, which can be a huge overhead (50%-200% for elements of 8-16 bytes, depending on whether you are 32 or 64 bits.)
10. Because of their smaller size and contiguous-ness in memory, vectors are generally a much faster and much nicer data structure.
11. Ultimately, you must do your own measurement and benchmarking within your own codebase and with your own workloads and usage patterns. No one can give you a definite answer without complete information of those. So, if your elements are very large, immovable objects, and you do mostly insertions/deletion and very few lookups, then go ahead and use linked lists. Otherwise, use vectors.

You can take a look at [this benchmark](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/), comparing vector, list and deque. It might further help you decide to use vector!

Comment: RE points 4 and 9: These talk about the general case, but for buckets, we're commonly dealing with 0 to <5 items per bucket, so (re:4) resizing can be rather common depending on the growth strategy, and (re:9) vector too has non-negligible space overhead (three pointers/`size_t`s), which is constant but not amortized over many bucket entries.

Comment: @delnan: You are of course correct. I will edit my answer to include your points. But you know as well as I do that vector (or more generally, an array-like container) is the correct fall-back choice for people who can't or won't do their own case-specific benchmarks. I feel too much detail will unfairly and incorrectly bias them against vectors! I'm practically evangelizing for arrays and vectors here!

Comment: @delnan: Regarding your point about vector's space overhead, a linked list has the same overhead. Depending on the implementation, the linked list might store two pointers (to front and back) and even a size. Of course, it might just be a single pointer to the front (and the list will be circular) but in any case, a list has comparable space overhead too.

Comment: I absolutely agree that `vector` or another container with continuous storage should be used. But for one or two items, it's probably not *more* space efficient than a linked list.